# Is there any way to break down my Google Cloud Functions spending into each one of my functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless, cost-management, google-cloud-billing

I want to know how much is each one of my cloud functions spending (break up the total costs on Google Cloud Functions that is shown in my Billing Console). I know I may be able to estimate it probably looking at the metrics and configuration of each function but it would be a hassle to do it one by one (I have a lot of functions).

I couldn't find any way of doing it using the Billing Console alone, it only shows the total cost.

If there was a tool/script it would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to  [add labels on each of your functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880081/changing-label-of-existing-gcp-cloud-functions) ([more about labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels)) and to sink the [billing in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery).

Now, you will be able to find the cost of each Cloud Functions label in BigQuery. Create a dashboard to view the summary, with [datastudio](https://datastudio.google.com/) for example.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked the labels thing because in the intro it mentions instances (compute instances) so I thought it only worked with those kinds of resources. Also I couldn't find a way to assign labels in the Cloud Functions dashboard. I will try using the API or cli, I guess it is possible that way.

Comment: For everyone coming here I found it is possible to add labels with the `gcloud functions deploy` command, but I couldn't make it with the `firebase deploy` command (which is the one I use). So I guess I will use the rest api.

Comment: It should be noted here that the BigQuery portion of this solution is not necessary. Once you've added labels, you can group by label in the billing console.

Comment: You couldn't filter with label in the console previously!

Comment: is there a way to add a label to the cloud function via console? I looked through all the settings and it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Yes you can. Follow the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#create-labels

Answer (score -1):

I am unaware of any tool in Billing that would help with what you are after.  And I don't think that Google's infrastructure is set up for what you are after.

The [Cloud Function Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing) document details how pricing is broken down.

But understand that your Cloud Functions are actually [deployed inside of a single (kubernetes) container](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/) and run inside of GCP.  The GCP infrastructure is able to monitor that container's CPU use, and monitor individual calls to your Cloud Functions, but I strongly doubt that it is monitoring the CPU use of each and every invocation of a function (consider how complex that would be in a project where there is high load/concurrency...how would that even work?)

Your question is specific to a particular approach to solving a problem.  I suggest you detail what the underlying problem is to see if there might be a different solution than "Google Billing breaking up Cloud Function costs".

Comment: I think the underlying problem is that we have many teams (each team working on a separate "project") using the same GCP project, and we need to separate the costs that each team is generating. Each team has deployed a bunch of functions.

Comment: btw, I am not sure if all my functions are inside a single container, if that is what you mean, because as far as I understand google creates a new container instance for each concurrent request on each cloud function. Each of these instances can only handle one request at a time https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances

Comment: I don't see any evidence that there is a breakdown of Cloud Functions as a service beyond project-level memory, CPU, invocation and network.  My experience and their documentation leads me to think of GCP's "project" being the level of granularity I expect from the services they offer.  Seems like your team has decided to use a single GCP project to do multiple "sub-projects" and are now struggling with the billing granularity.  I'd be interested to know if you find a solution.  I don't see a path to one.

Comment: Labels are the solution